# Client-side database ID persistence for shopping cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, local-storage, client-side, shopping-cart

I'm building a client side shopping cart. I have saved the shopping cart details(items purchased) on client side. During checkout I have to send the details to application server written in rails. I'm saving database 'id' field in my client side, which will be sent to server to identify the product. 
Is there any security issue in storing the raw id field in client-side? or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

WebStorage (local and session) follow [single origin policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#cross-directory-attacks). So it is safe, in the sense that only your server and your user can see the storage.